# Can we return a multiple result set in stored procedure and how to handle it in .net

Tags: stored-procedures

Can we return a multiple result set in stored procedure and how to handle it in .net

???
if yes how??
if no why not ??
please explain

Comment: I guess googling and self exploring of this would have saved more time and given you a notch of more understanding :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1a7f4f.aspx has some good examples.

you need to change your `connectionString` to support it. `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf.aspx for config settings;

Comment: You don't need to enable MARS. .net has been able to handle multiple resultsets forever

Answer (score 3):

If you are retrieving data using DataReader, you can use NextResult method to iterate through multiple resultsets returned by stored procedure. More information can be found [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
The following code is a simple example from MSDN:

```
static void RetrieveMultipleResults(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories;" +
          "SELECT EmployeeID, LastName FROM dbo.Employees",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetName(0),
                reader.GetName(1));

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
            reader.NextResult();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are populating a Dataset from a DataAdapter, note that if DataAdapter encounters multiple resultsets, it will create multiple DataTables (one for each resultset) and will add them to the resulting DataSet.